# Checkboxes checked by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm using [CheckboxGroupInput](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#checkboxgroupinput) in a field with many checkboxes, and I'd like them to be checked by default.

I tried using the `options attribute` like this:

```
<CheckboxGroupInput source="foo" choices={[
  { id: 0, name: 'bar' },
  { id: 1, name: 'bar' }
]} options={{
  checked: true
}}/>
```

But no luck, all checkboxes are checked by default, but they are not usable: they can't be unchecked nor are sent in the POST/PUT request.

Thanks!

PS: A `check all` button also could be nice, if someone has implemented one I'd be happy to see how it was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [defaultValue](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CreateEdit.html#default-values) on the form including this input.

About the *Check all* button, this can be implemented in a [custom input](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component). You might copy/paste the code of the `CheckboxGroupInput` and implement the logic in it.

About converting back the values into numbers, use the normalize prop:

```
<CheckboxGroupInput
    normalize={value => value.map(v => parseInt(v, 10))}
    source="notifications"
    choices={[
        { id: 12, name: 'Ray Hakt' },
        { id: 31, name: 'Ann Gullar' },
        { id: 42, name: 'Sean Phonee' },
    ]}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `defaultValue`.

Comment: By the way, I set the Id's as number, but after you check them manually they are sent as string, there's a way to keep them as number?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [normalize](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/Field.md/#-code-normalize-value-previousvalue-allvalues-previousallvalues-gt-nextvalue-code-optional-) prop:

Comment: Edited my answer with an example for normalize

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm honestly not familiar with react or admin-on-rest, so I could be way off here, but couldn't you put the `checked: true` part into the choices objects? (ie: `{ id: 0, name: 'bar', checked: true }`)

Comment: That doesn't work, it seems that that option is not implemented in `admin-on-rest`.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason is:** when you are using `checked` attribute that means you are making it [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and value of checked is always true:

`checked : true`

That's why its status is not getting changed.

Instead of `checked` use `defaultChecked`, Like this:

```
options={{
    defaultChecked: true
}}
```

Check the **[DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox)**:

> **defaultChecked**   ===>   bool  ===>  The default state of our checkbox component.
> Warning: This cannot be used in conjunction with checked. Decide
> between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove
> one of these props.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that does not work properly in admin-on-rest either.

Comment: This is not working for me. I used {{checked: true}} it works but can't be unchecked again. @Mayank How can I make checked initially and change behavior after that?